# Problem in loading data from firebase to android app

Tags: android, excel, firebase

I have an application where anybody can search the number & as output it shows the information for that number. Data is being loaded from Google excel sheet to the firebase (i.e my firebase is linked with google excel sheet) i add 5000 number data currently to the excel and saved to the firebase.

When i open my android app in phone data loading is too slow and my phone hangs until all data comes up. I need a solution for that because i have 700 million mobile number data. if i upload that data to firebase through excel, then my app doesn't handle this.

Is there any way to speed up the loading time for data from firebase to app  and storage?

Below i attached the screenshot of my app.

[image: X]

Comment: Please don't use indian words like 'crore' here. People from other countries will not understand it.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"